# $http.post() does not work - (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am trying to create a form with a dropdown input field and a submit button in AngularJS. Everything works fine except the output is empty xD. I am using `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>`. And if it's any help on server side I am using `PHP Version 5.5.36-1+donate.sury.org~trusty+1`.

Here's the Angular code:

```
        var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.myTxt = "You have not clicked submit, yet!";
            $scope.show_result = false;

            $scope.myFunc = function() {
                $scope.myTxt = "You clicked submit!";
                $scope.show_result = true;
            }

            $scope.categories = [
                {"value": 0, "categoryname": "standard"},
                {"value": 1, "categoryname": "premium"},
                {"value": 2, "categoryname": "gold"}
            ];

            $scope.submitData = function() {
                $scope.category = {};
                console.log($scope.category);
                var jsonString = JSON.stringify($scope.category);
                $http.post('ServerController.php', jsonString, {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
                        .success(function(data, status) {
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.data = data;
                        });
            }
        });
```

Here is the ServerController.php :

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $form_data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
        if ($form_data != null) {
            echo 'Success!!!';
            var_dump($form_data);
        } else {
            echo 'Sorry!!!';
            var_dump($form_data);
        }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="plunker">    
                <form ng-submit="myFunc()" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                    <label><b>Category:</b></label>
                    <select ng-model="category" ng-options="x.categoryname for x in categories track by x.value">
                        <option value="">Choose a Category</option>
                    </select>
                    <p><b>Model:</b> {{category}}</p>
                    <input ng-click="submitData()" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                    <i>{{myTxt}}</i>
                    <p ng-show="show_result"><b>Submitted result:</b> {{data}}</p>
                </form>
            </body>
```

Here is how the form looks on page load:

[image]

This is after you select category in the dropdown:

[image]

And finally after clicking submit:

[image]

Note: The server controller is sending the output in **Submitted result** ie. `Sorry!!!<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'> <b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i> <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i> </pre>`

Any ideas?

Comment: `{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}` this shouldn't be in the config, it should be in the headers.

Comment: try using `var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}`

Comment: `$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});`

Comment: @Callum so far I've seen so many examples online where `Content-Type` is set in the same manner. Though I am confused about the shorthand I am using against what you suggested. Will give it a try

Comment: Tried but still won't work. I think I need to start again from scratch. Could be syntax error.